# Is there a way to manually trigger reindexing resources in Xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm using VS2015 Xamarin Android.

When I add a new string resource or make a change to an id in one of my layouts the reindexing and generation for Resource.designer.cs does not happen automatically.

Maybe it's because my project is really big? I have no idea.

The only way I have found to manually trigger it, is rename an axml file to add a space to its end and then remove it, this updates the designer file.

Is there a better method to do this?

Comment: For me "rebuild all" helps.

Comment: for me it breaks everything, after I rebuild I loose all references to the current project's Resource, so Android.Resource.Layout...... works, but Resource.Layout.my_activity cannot be found, it still compiles and runs correctly but intellisense can't find it

Comment: @Cruces Have you tried to clean the project before rebuild? If it still not working, you could try to manually delete the `bin` and `obj` folder.

Comment: yes that's pretty much my standard procedure before most tests, clean , rebuild, delete bin obj, clean, rebuild, deploy to device for testing. But that still breaks intellisense, the only way to fix this is close and reopen the project, or do the whole rename a resource and rename it back in order for the project to be able to find resources correctly and not mark them as errors

Comment: I think it's better to use VS2017 instead of VS2015.

Comment: probably, but my company has not upgraded to that version yet